# Character Animation on OSX

Tags: macos, animation, lua

I want to do a 5-minute story for my kid on OSX. 
I have few characters and few scene and story will flow in it. 
I will have voice over and music on it

Is there an easy tool where I can author the animation? Other option, being writing the code to do the animation (maybe Lua or js), if writing code, a GUI interface would be good.

Any Suggestions?

Buying a software is also okay as I couple of stories.

Comment: I think you could try [Unity](https://unity3d.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do 3D animation, you might want to try [Blender](https://www.blender.org/).

Comment: mostly 2d, will look into Blender